# cmake -> libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: cmake, linker, pthreads

I am getting the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_key_delete@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

in a project built via `cmake`.
The actual command line generating that error is (I am copying only the relevant part)

```
/usr/bin/c++  ...  -lpthread -ldl -Wl,-Bstatic -lgtest -Wl,-Bdynamic ...
```

The error means that `-lpthread` should go after `-lgtest`.

After fixing that by hand, another error prompts me to moving `-lpthread` after `-Wl,-Bdynamic`. 
After that change, linking works ok with

```
/usr/bin/c++  ...  -ldl -Wl,-Bstatic -lgtest -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread ...
```

But I did this by hand at the command line.

**How should I modify my cmake configuration (either in `CMakeLists.txt` for my project, or elsewhere) to get the correct order of flags or remove the error?**

---

**Note**:
Trying to find out where can this be set, I ran

```
$ find . -type f -iname "*cmake*" -exec grep -B 4 -A 4 pthread {} \;
```

at the root of my project.
There is only one instance reported in `./CMake/FindMyprojMKL.cmake`

```
  set(MKL_LIBS
#      mkl_solver_lp64
      mkl_intel_lp64
      mkl_core
      pthread
      mkl_gnu_thread)
  message(STATUS "MKL_LIBS= ${MKL_LIBS}")
ELSE(MKL_LIBRARY)
  message(STATUS "Error: can not found MKL_LIBRARY")
```

I guess this is not the right place to fix the issue.

Comment: So link with `gtest` after linking with `pthread`. What are your CMakeLists sources?

Comment: @KamilCuk - I am not certain about what you mean by "link with `gtest` after linking with `pthread`".
Besides, are you asking about `CMakeLists.txt` files, or `Sources.cmake` files, or...? (there are a lot of both of them!)
Do you mean that I post one of them as an example?
Please see updated OP.